# problema al correr java en ventana en simbolo de sistema

Tags: java, cmd

al haber instalado el `jdk` me sale  un mensaje en la ventana del

> simbolo del sistema "javac no se reconoce como un comando interno o
>   externo"

ya no se que mas hacer porfa alguien me de una solucion

Comment: Necesitas agregar la ruta del bin de Java a las variables de entorno del sistema operativo

Comment: etas usando windows?

Answer (score 3):

Si estas trabajando en Windows debes proceder del modo siguiente

1. Ve al disco local (generalmente es C) y encuentra la carpeta de instalación de Java que debiste ya haber hecho; sería similar a la siguiente

---

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
```

Posterior a eso ingresa a la carpeta que se encuentra en su interior, hasta la caprta llamada bin, la ruta debe ser similar a esta

---

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin
```

Finalmente esta ruta la debemos dar de alta, en las variables de entorno, para que este disponible para el sistema completo:

1. Clic derecho en **Este Equipo**
2. Clic en **Propiedades**
3. Clic en **Configuración avanzada del sistema**
4. Clic en **Variables de entorno**

Para el paso anterior, tienes dos opciones

Variables de usuario->Esta opción te permitirá configurar un comando como el de `java` o `javac` solo para tu sesión

Variables del sistema-> Usaremos esta opción para dejar los comandos disponibles desde cualquier sesión de usuario iniciada

5. En variables de sistema, buscamos la que se llama `Path` **Ojo que se llame tal cual así**
6. Damos clic en editar o añadir
7. Finalmente agregamos la ruta completa que copiamos mas arriba; que es: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin`

Debes tener en cuenta que si tu sistema operativo es Windows 10 por ejemplo basta con
Dar clic en editar y añadir para añadir la ruta a las variables del sistema

En caso contrario, debe quedar similar a esto

```
ruta_deotro_programa_que_tengas;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin
```

Es decir como puedes notar separamos la ruta de un programa de otro por medio del punto y coma (**esto es necesario solamente si el SO es inferior a WIN10**)

**Resultado final**

```
C:\Users\User>java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```