# Como compilo estos archivos java?

Tags: java

Quisiera saber como compilar estos archivos java, porque intento desde cmd y me sale el error:

> "cannot find simbol".

***CargarDatos***

```
package tp2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CargarDatos {

public static Grafo<String> cargarDatos(String filename, String delimiter) {

    Grafo<String> grafo = new Grafo<>();
    // Primera pasada para agregar las peliculas y los actores como vertices del grafo
    try {   
        File file = new File(filename); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));     
        String st = null;
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {                
            String[] values = st.split(delimiter); 
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                if (!grafo.contieneVertice(values[i]))
                    grafo.agregarVertice(values[i]);
            }
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {         
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error al leer el archivo: " + filename); 
    } 

    // Segunda pasada para agregar aristas entre actores y peliculas en las que trabajaron
    try {   
        File file = new File(filename); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));     
        String st = null;
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {                
            String[] values = st.split(delimiter); 
            for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
                grafo.agregarArista(values[0], values[i]);
            }
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {         
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error al leer el archivo: " + filename); 
    } 

    return grafo;
}


// Ejemplo de uso:
//   java tp2.main "movies.txt"
// Ingrese un nombre:
//   Bacon, Kevin
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename  = args[0];
    String delimiter = "/";
    Grafo<String> grafo = cargarDatos(filename, delimiter);
    System.out.println("Cantidad de vertices: " + grafo.cantVertices());
    System.out.println("Ingrese un nombre: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new java.io.BufferedInputStream(System.in));
    String source = scanner.nextLine();
    if (grafo.contieneVertice(source)) {
        for (String v: grafo.obtenerAdyacentes(source)) {
            System.out.println("   " + v);
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No hay un vertice para la entrada: " + source);
    }
}


}
```

***Grafo***

```
package tp2;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Grafo<V> {

private Map<V, Set<V>> lAdy = new HashMap<>();

public Grafo() { }

public boolean contieneVertice(V v) {
    return lAdy.containsKey(v);
}

public void agregarVertice(V v) {
    lAdy.put(v, new HashSet<V>());
}

public void agregarArista(V v, V w) {
    lAdy.get(v).add(w);
    lAdy.get(w).add(v);
}

public Set<V> obtenerAdyacentes(V v) {
    return lAdy.get(v);
}

public int cantVertices() {
    return lAdy.keySet().size();
}

}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el comando que utilizas para compilar? Asegúrate que en las variables de entorno del Sistema Operativo esté agregado el jre de Java y si no necesariamente requieres del cmd, puedes descargar un IDE como Netbeans, Eclipse, Intellij idea, etc. y compilarlo desde las opciones que te proporciona el IDE.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/219640/problema-al-correr-java-en-ventana-en-simbolo-de-sistema/219646#219646 si necesitas configurar Java para compilar desde el cmd revisa esta respuesta que di hace unos dias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada, debes asegurarte que tienes el compilador instalado; bueno para eso ingresa el comando `javac` en la línea de comandos (ejecuta `cmd.exe`); una vez que asegures que todo está correctamente funcionando deberás colocarte en la ruta donde tienes tu clase.

Por ejemplo: `C:\CargarDatos.java`; para compilarlo ejecutas la siguiente sentencia:

```
javac CargarDatos.java
```

Esto te genera un archivo llamado `CargarDatos.class`, y para ejecutar el código compilado en la Consola escribes:

```
java CargarDatos
```

Muy importante, no se coloca la extensión del archivo (es decir el `.class`). Y listo así es como compilas desde `cmd`.

Encontrarás más información en: [Cómo Compilar y Ejecutar archivos Java desde la Consola cmd](https://gl-epn-programacion-ii.blogspot.com/2013/01/como-ejecutar-java-desde-la-consola-cmd.html)

Comment: Edité tu respuesta para dar formato de código, sugiero que le des clic a _editar_ y observes como se hace, pues eso, en general mejora la calidad de la respuesta. Un saludo.

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar, gracias!!!

Comment: Te agradezco @jachguate , mejoraré!

Comment: Que bueno @Shuzam, ojala pudieras marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Claro siempre y cuando lo haya sido.